# Searching in Arrays and Search and Traversing Trees

Tags: c++

Struggling with my last assignment of the semester. Not looking for "answers" just looking for some insight.. it's been a long time since my last actual programming class and since this is a data structures class, we don't review code. Assignment:

Program for Searching in Arrays and Search and Traversing Trees.

> 1. Ask the user to enter the name of the input data file
> 2. Load 150 random ordered values from a file into an array in unsorted order. Print out the array to ensure random order is maintained.
> 3. Load the same 150 random ordered numbers into a binary search tree. Print out the traversal of the tree in prefix, infix and postfix order to ensure binary tree created properly.
> 4. Load the same 150 random number ordered numbers into an array. Use ANY sort routine you want to write to order the numbers into ascending order. Print out the array to ensure numbers are in ascending sequence.
> 5. Using a counting loop ask the user to enter 10 numbers – the user will enter 5 numbers that are in the list and 5 that are NOT in the list.
>
>    - a. Search each data structure and count the number of comparisons needed to find the value or determine that the number is not in the list.
>    - i.  Unsorted array – use a linear search
>    - ii. Binary search tree – binary search
>    - iii.    Sorted array – binary search
>
> b.    Print out the results in a table format for each search
>
> - i.  Value
> - ii. “found”/”not found”
> - iii.    Number of comparisons linear search
> - iv. Number of comparisons binary search tree
> - v.  Number of comparisons binary search array
>
> c.    Print out summary
>
> - i.  Total number of comparisons linear search
> - ii. Total number of comparisons binary search tree
> - iii.    Total number of comparisons binary search array

Code so far, I know I am off:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

struct bintreenode {
    int value;
    struct bintreenode* l;
    struct bintreenode* r;
} *root = NULL, *temp = NULL;

typedef struct bintreenode N;

void insert();
N* bt(int arr[], int, int);
N* new(int);

void infix(N* t);
void prefix(N* t);
void postfix(N* t);

void main() {
    ifstream inputData;
    ofstream outputData;
    string fileName;
    cout << "Enter the name of the input data file: " << endl;
    //asks user to input filename
    cin >> fileName; //inputs user input into fileName
    return 1;
    ifstream file("file.txt");
    if (file.is_open()) {
        string myArray[150];
        for (int i = 0; i < 150; ++i) {
            file >> myArray[i];
        }
    }
    int ch, i, n;
    int arr[] = {
        1, 2, 3, 4, 136, 137, 138, 139, 56, 78, 9, 10,
        16, 17, 18, 58, 59, 60, 61, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23,
        24, 118, 119, 120, 121, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 128,
        129, 130, 131, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41,
        42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 145, 146, 147, 148, 11, 12, 13,
        14, 15, 47, 48, 49, 55, 56, 57, 62, 63, 64, 30, 31,
        32, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 142, 143,
        144, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 50, 51, 52, 53, 80, 81, 82,
        83, 85, 91, 92, 96, 93, 94, 95, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101,
        102, 103, 104, 105, 54, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111,
        112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126,
        127, 132, 133, 84, 86, 87 88, 89, 90, 134, 135, 140, 141,
        149, 150
    };

    n = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
    printf("\n1- infix\n");
    printf("2 - postfix\n");
    printf("\nEnter 10 numbers in the list and 10 numbers not in the list : ");
    scanf("%d", &ch);
    switch (ch) {
    case 1:
        root = bt(arr, 0, n - 1);
        printf("Given infix traversal as input\n");
        for (i = 0; i <= 6; i++)
            printf("%d->", arr[i]);
        printf("\nprefix traversal of tree\n");
        prefix(root);
        printf("\ninfix traversal of tree\n");
        infix(root);
        printf("\npostfix traversal of tree\n");
        postfix(root);
        break;
    case 2:
        insert();
        printf("\nprefix traversal of tree\n");
        prefix(root);
        printf("\nInfix traversal of tree\n");
        infix(root);
        printf("\npostfix traversal of tree\n");
        postfix(root);
        break;
    default:
        printf("enter correct choice");
    }

    /* To create a binary search tree */
    N* bt(int arr[], int first, int last) {
        int mid;
        N* root = (N*)malloc(sizeof(N));
        if (first > last)
            return NULL;
        mid = (first + last) / 2;
        root = new(arr[mid]);
        root->l = bt(arr, first, mid - 1);
        root->r = bt(arr, mid + 1, last);
        return root;
    }
    /* to print infix of tree */
    void infix(N* t) {
        if (t->l != NULL)
            infix(t->l);
        printf("%d->", t->value);
        if (t->r != NULL)
            infix(t->r);
    }
    /* to print prefix traversal of tree */
    void prefix(N* t) {
        printf("%d->", t->value);
        if (t->l != NULL)
            infix(t->l);
        if (t->r != NULL)
            infix(t->r);
    }
    /* to print postfix traversal of tree */
    void postfix(N* t) {
        if (t->l != NULL)
            infix(t->l);
        if (t->r != NULL)
            infix(t->r);
        printf("%d->", t->value);
    }
    bool tree::search(int num) {
        node* temp = head;
        while (temp != NULL) {
            if (temp->data == num)
                break;
            if (num > temp->data)
                temp = temp->right;
            else
            if (num < temp->data)
                temp = temp->left;
        }
        if (temp == NULL)
            printf("Not Found");
        if (temp->data == num)
            printf("Found");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe this needs to be moved to code review

Comment: @NathanOliver "I know I am off" indicates that the author knows that it's buggy.  That makes it off-topic for Code Review.

Comment: Your problems may lie with the incorrect definition of `main`.  The `main` function returns an `int`.  Always.

Comment: Advice - Start out with 10 *known* numbers to determine if your basic design works.  Trying to debug using 150 numbers, let alone random numbers, will get you frustrated.  Once you determine it works for 10 known numbers, then you see what happens when given more numbers.

Comment: By the way, execution stops after processing a `return` statement in `main`.  See the lines where you input the filename.

Comment: Don't hardcode the significance of 150 in your program. Create that array using a for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some issues I found:

### Don't cross the streams

```
    #include <stdio.h>  
    #include <iostream>
    #include <fstream>
```

Use either C or C++ streams; prefer C++ streams.  If you need definitions from `stdio.h` us `<cstdio>`.
Don't use `cout` and `printf`.  Decide; one or the other.

### Coding Style: Word distinguishing in identifiers

Use a coding style that allows readers to separate the hidden names in an identifer.
Poor:

```
struct bintreenode
```

Better:

```
struct bin_tree_node
struct binTreeNode
struct BinTreeNode
```

Coding Style:  names not single letters
Prefer names for identifiers over single letters:
Poor:

```
struct bintreenode *l;
struct bintreenode *r;
```

Better:

```
struct bintreenode *left_subtree;
struct bintreenode *right_subtree;
```

Using more descriptive identifers has no impact to your executable and negligible impact on the build process.  It has a great positive impact to people reading your code, including you.

### Use data from the User

You prompt the User for a filename, yet you hard code one:

```
cout << "Enter the name of the input data file: " << endl;
//asks user to input filename
cin >> fileName; //inputs user input into fileName
return 1;

ifstream file("file.txt");
```

Also, the `return 1` above will cause execution to stop at that point.  No more execution, so the file is never opened.

Don't name variables after their structure.
Poor:

```
int arr[] = {1, /*...*/, 150};
n = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
```

Better:

```
static const int test_values[] = {1, /* ... */, 150};
static const unsigned int quantity_test_values =
    sizeof(test_values) / sizeof(test_values[0]);
```

If the content of the struct will not be modified, prefer to use `const` prefix.
If the variable is not global, prefer to add `static` to the declaration.

### Terminate your output with newline

Your text may not be completely printed, as some text may reside in a buffer.  Usually printing a newline ('\n') or `std::endl` will flush the buffers and print the remaining text.

### Use a Debugger

Before posting here with a "why doesn't it work" question, use a debugger and single step through each statement.  Examine variables for correct values.
Add print statements (a.k.a. `cout`) to print out values.